# build.gradle: conditionally include features in a product variant

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I have a project with several product variants.
At the moment I am using the following way to specify whether I want to include a specific functionality - at the end of my build.gradle file I do this:

```
productFlavors
{
    customapp1 {
        applicationId "com.app.id1"
    },
    customapp2 {
        applicationId "com.app.id2"
    },
    ....
}
if(extensions_ads) {
dependencies {
    println "Adding ads dependencies"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
}

android.sourceSets.main {
    java.srcDirs += ['./src/extensions/ads'];
}
}
else{
    android.sourceSets.main {
        java.srcDirs += ['./src/extensions/noads'];
    }
}
```

As you see extensions_ads is a global variable, I would like to have something like:

```
productFlavors
{
    customapp1 {
        extensions_ads true
        applicationId "com.app.id1"
    },
    customapp1 {
        extensions_ads false
        applicationId "com.app.id1"
    }
}
```

1. How should I define extensions_ads to be part of the flavour definition.
2. How to traverse all the flavors and check for that flag?

Answer (score 0):

I would follow another logic to conditionate your dependencies or the sourceset resources.

You can add the dependencies only for a flavor, or a buildType or a buildVariant.

For example:

```
dependencies {
    flavor1Compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
}
```

At the same way you can use different folders for each flavor without the need to specify the `android.sourceSets` in your `build.gradle` file.

```
+ src
    + main 
        + java 
        + res
    + flavor1
        + java
        + res
    + flavor2
        + java
        + res
```

Of course if it is not enough you can specify the android.sourceSets for a flavor, somenthing like:

```
sourceSets{
        main {
          //
        }

        flavor1.java.srcDirs = [ ...] 
        flavor1.res.srcDirs = [ ... ]
        ...

        flavor2.java.srcDirs = [...] 
        flavor2.res.srcDirs = [...]
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Looks great, but my flavors  are too many, plus we have a script where they can be added automatically in the build.gradle file. I prefer some kind of traversing for all the flavors instead of 'hardcoding' the srcDirs for every flavor manually.